# Navier-Stokes on concentric cylinders

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

Consider incompressible fluid flowing between two fixed concentric cylinders of radii a and b with b>a, and length L. Radial distance is measured by r and axial distance along the cylinders is measured by z. The axis of the cylinder is vertical with z pointing upwards, and both ends are open to the atmosphere.

State appropriate no-slip boundary conditions and use these to obtain the flow $w$ in the form

[image: see picture]

---

*Progress*: 
I have gotten to integrating the equation with two constants and applied the boundary conditions
\begin{align*} 
 w\,(r= a) = &0, \\
 w\,(r= b) = &0  
\end{align*}

So I got,
\begin{align*} 
  w = \dfrac{\rho g}{4\,\mu}  r^2  + A\, \ln {r} + B \\
 A  = - \dfrac{\rho g}{4\,\mu} \, \ln\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)\,  
  \left( {a}^{2} - {b}^{2} \right)  \\ 
 B  = - \dfrac{\rho g}{4\,\mu} \,   
  \left( \ln(a)^{2}\,{b} - \ln(b)^{2}\, {a} \right)   
\end{align*}

After this, I am not quite sure how I can get the solution that was asked for, I have plugged A and B into the equation but still could not yield the desired result.

Comment: So, what is left is just the algebraic task of verifying an identity? I would start from the given form of equation, and split the logarithms $\log(r/a) = \log r - \log a$, obtaining the form $A'\log r+B'$. Then compare $A'$ with your $A$, and $B'$ with $B$.

Comment: I could not get them to match, so I was wondering if it was something wrong with my A and B

Comment: They are either equal or not; you could tell for sure by simplifying the difference with WolframAlpha. And if they are not equal, then your solution probably fails some of the boundary conditions, so you should re-check that by plugging in the BCs. Honestly, there isn't much for anyone else to say about a problem where we see neither the original problem (its PDE) nor your solution.